# No http headers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, http, uiwebview, nslog

I am trying to find the http headers but I don't think my method is working.
I am using

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSMutableURLRequest *req = (NSMutableURLRequest *)request;

NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [req valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);
NSLog(@"http headers = %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
NSLog(@"http headers = %@", [req allHTTPHeaderFields]);
```

}

But the NSLog is printing out

```
http headers = {
```

Both req and request are not nil. Does anyone know why I am unable to get the headers?

Thanks
Clinton

Comment: just out of curiosity, what happens when you try to print an NSDictionary? (just wondering, since that what allHTTPHeaderFields returns)

Comment: I just but this code in `NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.ca"]];
 NSLog(@"dic = %@", dic);` and it came back as dic = (null)